# Facebook Workplace API authentication

Tags: graph, oauth, facebook-workplace

I'm developing a web application that integrates with Facebook's Workplace. I've spent the whole day trying to figure out how to use OAUTH authentication mechanism for member authentication. 
Since I have the app access token I'm able to get member access tokens for impersonation. But, how do I get them using OAUTH? Is it even possible with Workplace Graph API?
Thanks in advance for the advice!

Comment: Just got word from the Facebook Developers Group that it's not possible to do that.

Comment: Hi there, any update on it? having same issue,