# Meteor app. Sign in with Facebook-Workplace instead of Facebook

Tags: authentication, meteor, facebook-workplace

I know the *accounts-facebook* package is very usefull when one wants users to sign in with their Facebook credentials, but is this also possible using Facebook Workplace accounts? I can't seem to find anything helpful on this subject and was wondering if anyone has run into this puzzle before..

Answer (score 1):

Per this [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42567559/facebook-workplace-api-authentication), Facebook Workplace doesn't expose an API for authenticating users, so it would not be possible to authenticate with it directly.

Facebook Workplace does, however, have support for several [SSO Providers](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/workplace/authentication/sso).  Most of these services have an AD bindings, which are supported by Meteor, so you could easily switch to using one of these services, and connect both Facebook Workplace and your Meteor app to that.